# Issues with Redirect in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, frameworks

I just started trying Laravel 4.1 today, and I've had to use a tutorial for Laravel 4.0, so I've had to troubleshoot certain parts of the code.
There's one part I couldn't troubleshoot, and i need some help with it.

These are the routes involved:

```
Route::get('authors/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'edit_author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@get_edit'));

Route::put('authors/update', array('uses'=>'AuthorsController@put_update'));
```

and these are the actions in the controller:

```
public function get_edit($id){
   return View::make('authors.edit')->with('title', 'Edit Author')->with('author', Author::find($id));
}

public function put_update(){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $author = array(
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'bio'  => Input::get('bio'),
            );
    $validation = Author::validate($author);
    if ($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('edit_author', $id);
    }else{
        Author::update($id, $author);
        return Redirect::route('view_author', $id);
    }
}
```

Note that in the routes i'm using {id} instead of (:any), because the latter didn't work for me.

On my browser the get_edit function runs ok at first, but then, when i click the submit button and it's supposed to execute put_update, whether it's supposed to redirect me to view_author or back to edit_author, it just gives me a NoFoundHttpException.

Just as additional information, i use the default .htacces which is this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `4.1` so it should be `{id}` not `(:any)` and make sure you are using the right way to generate form, like this:

```
Form::open(array('action' => array('AuthorsController@put_update', $author->id), 'method' => 'put'))
```

Also close the form using `Form::close()`. Since you are not using a `RESTful` controller so you can use a method name as `update` instead of `put_update` and for `RESTful` method use `putUpdate` not `put_update`. So, you may use a route like:

```
Route::put('authors/update', array('uses'=>'AuthorsController@update'));
```

Then the method should be:

```
public function update($id)
{
    // ...
    if ($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    }
    else{
        Author::update($id, $author);
        return Redirect::route('view_author', $id);
    }
}
```

So the form should be like:

```
Form::open(array('action' => array('AuthorsController@update', $author->id), 'method' => 'put'))
```

Also change your edit `route` to this:

```
Route::get('authors/edit/{id}', array('as'=>'edit_author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@edit'));
```

Make the change in the method as well:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.
Turns out i was opening my form like this:

<?php echo Form::open(array('url'=>'authors/update','_method'=>'PUT')); ?>

...since that's what i was doing in my "create" form and it was working fine. Now I've also changed my create form opening line...

Also, I AM using a restful controller... or so i think, since i did this in my controller "public $restful = true;"...

But then again this is my first day using laravel, so if you know of a tutorial for 4.1 i'd appreciate it, cuz it's not easy to work with a 4.0 tut.

Anyway, thank you very much for your help!